# Documents in elasticsearch getting deleted automatically?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I'm creating an index though `logstash` and pushing data to it from a MySQL database. But what I noticed in `elasticsearch` was once the whole data is uploaded, it starts deleting some of the docs. The total number of docs is 160729. Without the scheduler it works fine.

I inserted the cron scheduler in order to check whether new rows have been added to the table. Can that be the issue?

My `logstash` conf looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/ptxjpHJ9).

Where am I going wrong? Or is this behavior common?

Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docs.deleted` number doesn't mean that your documents are being deleted, but simply that existing documents are being "updated" and the older version of the updated document is marked as deleted in the process.

Those documents marked as deleted will be eventually cleaned up as Lucene merges segments in the background.